# Universal max length for EditText - Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-layout, maxlength

I know about the similar max length method for EditText that looks like this

`editText.maxLength = "21"`

But the problem is that this type of method isn't effective in my case. I have an EditText that has special dimension, so my goal is to not allow symbols to pass edittext's border. I nedd something that maximizes length of edittext more by dimension, than by symbols. Symbols have a different size, so maybe maxLength should be based on size of "M" symbol.

Works perfectly fine:

[image]

But when symbols bigger appear this happens:

[image]

Comment: What is that graphic on the left? It looks like a start drawable for the _EditText_, but I don't think it is because the text overlaps it. Are you OK if the number of n's in your example is less than the number that can fit as long as the M's don't exceed the bounds? Maybe you would like more n's to fit and actually exceed the number of M's allowed.

Comment: the max length for the edittext is 21 but the m's has bigger size, so they don't fit